# How to change the content of a page after form submit ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, panel

I have a main form that users fill out, and at the bottom there is a 'Submit' and 'Reset' button. As of now, there is a seperate .aspx confirmation page that users are directed to after pressing submit. Basically, I would like to be able to combine the confirm.aspx page into my default.aspx form page and have the content on the confirm.aspx page load on its own after the default.aspx page is submitted, without having two seperate pages. I feel like this might be pretty simple, but I'm still a beginner to ASP.net and have no clue as to how to approach this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ASP.NET Panel controls and toggle the visibility. Have a form panel, a success panel and an error panel. Populate the latter two with appropriate messages. The error panel would appear via the catch in a try/catch setup.

Comment: Went ahead and decided to use panels, seemed a bit simpler and lighter on code for a noob like myself. Thanks again bud!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the best solution for this request is to use a `MultiView` to separate the content. When working with Views, non-active views are not sent to the client, so it won't affect the size of your page.

Check out this [little tutorial](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com.br/2008/10/multiview-example-how-to-use-multiview.html).

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: edit you answer "non active view not sent to the clinet" I think they are present on the page but are hidden. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try as well. Link is blocked for me sadly, as i'm at work right now, but I'll do some searching around for the `MultiView` control.

Comment: @JacobZacharia see if you can access the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227440(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @WaqarJanjua just verified and it's right: MultiView sends absolutely no "trash" to the client, not even an empty HTML tag is included.